# Using Ember CLI and the ES6 syntax `export default` how do I know if the export is an Ember.Object

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I am using Ember CLI and the ES6 syntax `export default something`, I would really like to know if the `something` from my export was an Ember.Object. What could I check on the object to ensure that is an Ember.Object or extends Ember.Object?

```
// app/repos/wat.js
import Ember from "ember";

var wat = Ember.Object.extend({
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log("do stuff");
    }
});

export default wat;

// app/utils/wat.js
import Ember from "ember";
import wat from "../repos/wat";

console.log(wat instanceof Ember.Object);

// console.log above returns false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `instanceof`:

```
import SomeObject from 'some-place';
var isEmberObject = SomeObject instanceof Ember.Object;
```

EDIT: Sorry, I answered too quickly. That version only works for instances, not classes. To check if a class extends `Ember.Object`, you can do this:

```
import SomeClass from 'some-other-place';
var isEmberClass = SomeClass.prototype instanceof Ember.Object
```

You can also use [isPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf):

```
import SomeClass from 'some-other-place';
var isEmberClass = Ember.Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(SomeClass.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! When I try what you've suggested above, I get a false for instance of Ember.Object. I've updated my question to include a quick code example. Please let me know if that changes your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, you can still use `instanceof` to check for subclasses, you just have to check the prototype. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @GJK! the SomeClass.prototype instanceof Ember.Object worked perfectly.